# React/JavaScript create data model objects

Tags: reactjs, breeze, datamodel

I am coming from [breeze.js](https://breeze.github.io/doc-js/) and TypeScript to react and Ecmascript.

Breeze is a client side state library.

It has a [createEntity](https://breeze.github.io/doc-js/creating-entities.html) function that would create your data object, which typically matched your entity on the server side (C# Entity Framework for my case).

for example:

```
var newOrderDetail = 
    manager.createEntity<OrderDetail>('OrderDetail', {orderId: oid, productId: pid});
```

*newOrderDetail now has all the order properties, with orderId and productId set to default data passed in. And it's typed from from TypeScript as an OrderDetail interface*

It feels weird to be creating this directly on the state, it's like I don't have a good feel for what I'm working with.

```
this.state = {
  orderId: oid, 
  productId: pid,
  // .. all the other fields
};
```

Is there a library or strategy that could help with this?  It would be cool to do this:

```
this.state = createEntity('OrderDetail', {orderId: oid, productId: pid});
```

Could I just put a class object in state or is this a bad idea?

```
this.state = {
  order: new Order()
}
```

I don't like adding a level to the state since I'll have to always null check. Unless I could use the class object as state:

```
this.state = new Order();
```

I haven't found any client orm libraries for this or any examples doing things like this so I might trying to find a solution for a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: You won't find much examples for data models with React because they are orthogonal to how the state is commonly managed there. State needs to be synchronized with data model.

Comment: @estus - do you have an example to illustrate this?

Comment: Nope. I don't have much experience with Breeze. I'd say you have to subscribe on model changes and update component state, and vice versa, that's at least this is one of possible ways to work with it. I'm not sure how they expect https://breeze.github.io/doc-js/model-library.html#backingStore to work with React, because this approach doesn't seem to be reactive-friendly. Breeze isn't very popular on SO, I'd suggest to open an issue regarding proper documentation for the use with React.

Comment: @estus - Sorry I'm not looking to make breeze work with react that was just to give background of what I am coming from. I was asking if you could give an example of how data models are orthogonal to state in react, I don't really understand what you meant there.